# I want to make a splash screen made with multiple images

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to make a random splash screen, so that everytime I open the app another image will be loaded.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    private int[] splashImages = {R.drawable.splash1, R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.splash3};
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int postOfImage = random.nextInt(splashImages.length -1);
```

Could someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Corina, is above code working or not? or is any problem coming in it?

Comment: Use `Animation menuAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.animator.menu_off_animation);`. Define your animation in xml file.

Comment: yahh.. Use animation utils or make a small video of it and put the video at startup at splashscreen

but in video result is not so good... so kindly use the Animation Utils

Comment: It worked when I was using in the splash screen one image, I was using this code: 
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                *//* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. *//*
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,ActivityTypes.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);

Comment: @CorinaRacasan ya right, you can achieve this Random function dear, everytime new image will show

Comment: so now what is the problem ?

Comment: It is not working with the random.

Comment: @CorinaRacasan its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int[] splashImages = { R.drawable.splash1, R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.splash3 };
    ImageView imgSplash;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        imgSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        int selected;
        selected = randomBox();
        if (selected == sharedPreferences.getInt("SELECTED", 0)) {
            selected = randomBox();
        }

        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("SELECTED", selected);
        editor.commit();

        for (int i = 0; i < splashImages.length; i++) {
            if (selected == i) {
                imgSplash.setImageResource(splashImages[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    public static int randomBox() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(splashImages.length);
        return pickedNumber;

    }

}
```

Comment: @CorinaRacasan hellow, is this working fine for you?

Comment: @CorinaRacasan hey u busy? I just wanna know about this answer.

Comment: Oh I am very sorry for my late answer. Yes, this workied for me, my problem is now solved. Thank you very much @pratik